# Simple Quiz Android

Tags: java, android, class, button, android-studio

EDITED *

Now the question is if I need to create 11 TextView more on my design, or I can use the same TextView for each question? And I have initialized to 1, because the TextView that it shows is TextView.

```
public class MyActivity4 extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int nivellactual=1;
    private int elementcorrecte;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity4);
    TextView tvJuego = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJuego);
    tvJuego.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 3, Color.GRAY);
    ImageButton borojuego,berijuego,cobajuego,hidrojuego,indijuego,plutojuego,sodijuego,molijuego,zicrojuego
            ,promjuego,ununjuego,radijuego;



    berijuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibBeriJuego);
    borojuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibBoroJuego);
    cobajuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibCobaJuego);
    indijuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibIndiJuego);
    hidrojuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibHidroJuego);
    ununjuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibUnunJuego);
    plutojuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibPlutoJuego);
    radijuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibRadiJuego);
    promjuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibPromJuego);
    sodijuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibSodiJuego);
    zicrojuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibZicroJuego);
    molijuego=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibMoliJuego);
    berijuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    borojuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    cobajuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    indijuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    hidrojuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    ununjuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    plutojuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    radijuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    promjuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    sodijuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    zicrojuego.setOnClickListener(this);
    molijuego.setOnClickListener(this);





}
private void seguentelement() {

    switch (nivellactual) {

        case 1:

            TextView tvPregunta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta)//WARNING ERROR;
            String pregunta = ("Quin element és el Hidrògen?");
            tvPregunta.setText(pregunta);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibHidroJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 2:

            TextView tvPregunta2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta)//WARNING ERROR;
            String pregunta2 = ("Quin element és el Indio?");
            tvPregunta2.setText(pregunta2);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibIndiJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 3:

            TextView tvPregunta3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta)//WARNING ERROR;
            String pregunta3 = ("Quin element és el Cobalto?");
            tvPregunta3.setText(pregunta3);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibCobaJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 4:

            TextView tvPregunta4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta);
            String pregunta4 = ("Quin element és el Berilio?");
            tvPregunta4.setText(pregunta4);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibBeriJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 5:

            TextView tvPregunta5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta)//WARNING ERROR;
            String pregunta5 = ("Quin element és el Prometio?");
            tvPregunta5.setText(pregunta5);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibPromJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 6:

            TextView tvPregunta6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta)//WARNING ERROR;
            String pregunta6 = ("Quin element és el Radio?");
            tvPregunta6.setText(pregunta6);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibRadiJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 7:

            TextView tvPregunta7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta)//WARNING ERROR;
            String pregunta7 = ("Quin element és el Plutonio?");
            tvPregunta7.setText(pregunta7);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibPlutoJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 8:

            TextView tvPregunta8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta);
            String pregunta8 = ("Quin element és el Ununstrio?");
            tvPregunta8.setText(pregunta8);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibUnunJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 9:

            TextView tvPregunta9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta)//WARNING ERROR;
            String pregunta9 = ("Quin element és el Sodio?");
            tvPregunta9.setText(pregunta9);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibSodiJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 10:

            TextView tvPregunta10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta)//WARNING ERROR;
            String pregunta10 = ("Quin element és el Boro?");
            tvPregunta10.setText(pregunta10);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibBoroJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 11:

            TextView tvPregunta11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta)//WARNING ERROR;
            String pregunta11 = ("Quin element és el Zicronio?");
            tvPregunta11.setText(pregunta11);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibZicroJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
        case 12:

            TextView tvPregunta12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta)//WARNING ERROR;
            String pregunta12 = ("Quin element és el Molibdeno?");
            tvPregunta12.setText(pregunta12);
            //PENSANDO
            elementcorrecte = (R.id.ibMoliJuego);//load here the id of the correct answer of each level)
            break;
    }
}
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){

        //when clicking the correct id, transict to other level, and load new data
        if (v.getId() == elementcorrecte) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Correcte!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            nivellactual++;
            seguentelement();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error!! :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this logic helps:

```
//currentLevel and correctAnswer vars
private int currentlevel;
private int correctAnswer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //load all your UI
}

private void levelTransition()
{
   //for each level, load specific text and images
   switch(currentlevel)
   case 1:
   String pregunta=("Quin element és el Hidrògen?");
   tvPregunta.setText(pregunta);
   //... and other things
   correctAnswer = (...) //load here the id of the correct answer of each level
   break;
   case 2:
   //...
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //when clicking the correct id, transict to other level, and load new data
    if(v.getId() == correctAnswer)
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Correcte!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            currentlevel++;
            levelTransition();
            }
    else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error!! :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            }
```

Comment: I think this will help me a lot, thanks a lot @PedroHawk, I hope you do not mind if I'm asking to you when I'm implementing the code, I'm new and I'm trying to learn.. The first thing that I don't know how to do is on correctAnswer=(...) Inside of "()" how can I put the ImageButton answer? Or if I put the id of the ImageButton it will work

Comment: on your question, u have a switch case with the R.id.* of the correct or wrong imagebuttons. The logic is the same, but you store the R.id.* (_of the correct one_) on **correctAnswer** var any time you load that specific level.

Comment: But how do I set an ImageButton or ID to an int? Because correctanswer is an Int and if I try to put ID / ImageButton / etc.. it doesn't work, that's why i'm asking to you how do I put the Id of correct ImageButton to int

Comment: check your own question right on **switch case**. `int id = v.getId();` That result is an int of the button, imagebutton or whatever you clicked. if that matches with the correctAnswer ID (previously stored), is correct!

Comment: Yes, of course i'll upvote you, your logic helped me a lot! check what I have edited on my code please..

Comment: thats right. now for each question you need to load your imagebuttons with answers programatically (something like **.settext(text)** or **.setimagedrawable(drawable)**

Answer (score 0):

**XML:**
You can use the question and the answers as textViews.
in the XML give IDs to your views for example (questionView, answer1View, answer2View...). 
**Java:** 
use a counter to know in which question is the current.
make a switch case on the counter.
for each case you can use questionView.setText("blabla").
also implement onClickListener on the answers views which will make the action right or wrong and most important will increment the counter and will call the method with the switch cases.